# Macro to convert a Unix integer into a datetime

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

So as the title state's, I have a field that has a unix int that I need to convert into a datetime in snowflake (using dbt macros's) - I can do this in SQL easily enough, but am really struggling to get around dbt's escape clauses.

I've tried every possible approach I can find in google, the closest I've come so far is using the `{% raw %}` tag - which works if I just hard code a value, but I want to be able to use the macro's input parameter:

**This works**

```
{%- macro num_to_datetime(datetime_field) -%}
{% raw %}
    DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1683668421712 % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, 1683668421712 / 1000, '19700101'))
{% endraw %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

**This doesn't**

```
{%- macro num_to_datetime(datetime_field) -%}
{% raw %}
    DATEADD(MILLISECOND, {{ datetime_field }} % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, {{ datetime_field }}/ 1000, '19700101'))
{% endraw %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

I've tried using the `{% set %}` tag to set the input parameter as a variable, but this still, doesn't seem to work (Likely just a syntax issue)

Any help or advice is appreciated (side note: I hate this damned language)

**EDIT:** Just to add, the use case for doing this in a macro is for automation purposes, we read our metadata in python and generate staging view scripts which parse from json and add business friendly column headers etc. We also use this to apply default macros to certain fields, so that ingesting new source data is as simple as a few clicks the performing a dbt run.

Comment: so to clarify, you want the epoch to datetime, inside DBT space, so it can be used in other DBT steps, verse wanting the convertion done in Snowflake? Which is to ask 'while the end result will be used in Snowflake, this is not a Snowflake question?'

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim 
yes, must be done in dbt - as our entire framework is based off the "Infrastructure as code" methodology, so if something happens we can spin up everything from the repo with minimal effort.

We're too far down the road to change that now, everything is already well established. This has only become an issue now as we're in the process of changing our ingestion pipeline from an outdated ETL tool that handled all these conversions for us before sending a file to a direct/streaming approach straight from the vendors datalake.

Comment: That sounds understandable, I was just considering removing the Snowflake TAG as the problem is not actually a Snowflake problem.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, good point. I will remove the snowflake tag. Apologies, I misread your initial comment.

I've managed to find a working solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, using the snowflake function `TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ()`

full macro here for anyone that may want to use it in future:

```
{%- macro num_to_datetime(epochs, format="milliseconds") -%}
    {%- if format == "seconds" -%}
    {%- set scale = 0 -%}
    {%- elif format == "milliseconds" -%}
    {%- set scale = 3 -%}
    {%- elif format == "microseconds" -%}
    {%- set scale = 6 -%}
    {%- else -%}
    {{ exceptions.raise_compiler_error(
        "value " ~ format ~ " for `format` for from_unixtimestamp is not supported."
        )
    }}
    {% endif -%}
    to_timestamp_ntz({{ epochs }}, {{ scale }})
{%- endmacro %}
```

Comment: ah, but this is a solution inside, Snowflake, not in DBT? As per my question. But if thus this was a snowflake question. I had thought you were wanting the "datetime" in DBT so you could do onther processes like name a file by the datetime, as compared to how in snowflake SQL do I convert a epoch to datetime, which you have found the correct solution.

Comment: To be fair, it's kind of both. Doing it inside snowflake is simple enough as it's really just straight sql. 

Getting dbt to do it in snowflake so that it's repeatable and can be automated was the part that I was stuck on. I thought you meant physically coding the solution in Snowflake which isn't an option in my use case.